# JQuery: Show child element that is within a hidden parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a series of menus and submenus (nested uls). I want to display a ul that is nested within another parent ul, without displaying the parent. I would normally do this as:

```
$('#menu ul li ul').show(300);
```

but because the original, parent ul has `display:none` css, the child ul does not show.

I have tried adding:

```
$('#menu ul:first').addClass('nodisplay');
```

But this doesnt really work either.

Can anyone suggest a way to to do this?

Comment: The child is contained within the parent. If you hide the parent, you hide the child.

Comment: you should move it to dom tree which is displayed

Comment: Can't be done, you'll have to move the child UL, or show the parent UL.

Comment: Reopen : There is a solution here, to use visibility in the class.

Comment: This could be a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/U6XAG/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it with jQuery and append it to a visible parent, then destroy it when it was no longer needed.